# Redirection in controller in MVC 3 with Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, redirect, razor

I need a little help. I'm trying to make a little project in MVC 3 with Razor. A page with 2 buttons: Button 1 and Button 2. When I click on Button 1 I want to go at Page 1. The same with Button 2 ( to Page 2). It's not difficult, BUT I want the redirection to be made in Controller, not in View (cshtml). I know that I need to use ActionName and RedirectToAction, but I don't know how. Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll need to do is check which button was pressed in the HttpPost part of the controllers action then redirect accordingly.

As a very basic example you could add two

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="<val>">
```

controls into your forms view each having the same name and a different value (instead of ) then add a string parameter called submit to the HttpPost action. Assuming the buttons have values "button1" and "button2" Then in your action's code you could use:

```
if(submit == "button1") {
  RedirectToAction("Page1");
} else {
  RedirectToAction("Page2");
}
```

to redirect based on which button was pressed

Answer (score 0):

In your controller action for page 1, you can use `RedirectToAction`:

```
public ActionResult Process()
{
  // do processing

  // redirect to page 2
  return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Page2");
}
```

You can invoke the Process action from the Page 1 button using either a GET or POST request, depending on if the Process action is idempotent. E.g your page 1 view:

```
@Html.BeginForm("Process", "Page1", FormMethod.Post)
{
  <input type="submit" name="button" value="Submit" />
}
```

Alternatively, you could use an `ActionLink`:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Redirect to Page 2", "Process", "Page1")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplified example, but I think you will get my meaning.  You simply need to name your buttons and check the formcollection to see which exists in the collection thus indicating which what clicked. see code below:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    { 

        <input type="submit" value="Go 1" name="go-1" />
        <input type="submit" value="Go 2" name="go-2" />
    }
```

and now the Action implementation.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Test(FormCollection collection)
    {
        if (collection.AllKeys.Contains("go-1")) return View("Page1");
        if (collection.AllKeys.Contains("go-2")) return View("Page2");
        return View("Index");
    }
```

and thats it.